# Child node type to give to a function

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to create a recursive function that runs through an XML file, and analyse it's nodes.

I've created a function, called XML, that is like this :

```
function XML {
    param ([XML] $XMLDoc)

    if($XMLDoc.HasChildNodes){
        return XML XML.FirstChild
    } else {
        ...
}
```

I get my XML Document with this code :

```
$XMLDocPath = "W:\SomePath\file.xml"
$XMLDoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$XMLFile = Resolve-Path($XMLDocPath)
$XMLDoc.Load($XMLFile)
[XML] $XMLDoc = Get-content -Path $XMLDocPath
```

The problem is, that I want to give My XML Document to the `XML` function, but with a recursive calling, I have to give to this `XML` function the `XML.FirstChild` and `XML.NextSibling` objects, that are not the same type of objects.

My question is, What can I put in the `param ([...] $XMLDoc)` of the function, to be able to pass a node to this function, and not an XML object. What is the type of the `XMLDoc.FirstChild` ? The `XMLDoc.FirstChild.GetType()` gives me something but it cannot be put in the parameter's type.

To have :

```
if($XMLDoc.HasChildNodes){
    XML $XMLDoc.FirstChild
}
```

Instead of :

```
XML $XMLDoc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't give the parameter a fixed type if you want/need to pass arguments of varying types:

```
function XML {
    param($XmlObject)

    if($XmlObject.HasChildNodes){
        return XML $XmlObject.FirstChild
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, reduce your convoluted XML import to this:

```
$XMLDocPath = "W:\SomePath\file.xml"
[xml]$XMLDoc = Get-Content -Path $XMLDocPath
```